# include all files in folder and if empty show text

Tags: php, file, include, directory

Now i include all the files in a directory to my site with php using this code:

```
<?php   foreach (glob("overzicht/projects/*.php") as $filename)
{
 include $filename;
}
?>
```

But when the directory is empty I want him to show the text: "there are no files found in the directory."

How do i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$listy = glob("overzicht/projects/*.php");
if (empty($listy)) {
    echo "there are no files found in the directory";
} else {
  foreach ($listy as $filename) {
    include $filename;
  }
}
```

Comment: I upvoted, but you should change it to `if (!$listy || empty($listy))`, as according to the manual, glob `Returns an array containing the matched files/directories, an empty array if no file matched or FALSE on error.` __Note:__ `On some systems it is impossible to distinguish between empty match and an error.`

Comment: @Peter Never mind then. You're right (sort of, `empty(false)` gets you a syntax error lol).

Comment: @Peter, Corrected. Syntax Error in PHP Ver<=5.4, either that or my server is whack.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $flag = true;
    foreach (glob("overzicht/projects/*.php") as $filename)
    {
        include $filename;
        $flag = false;
    }
    if ($flag)
    {
        print("There are no files found in the directory.");
    }
?>
```

I'm sure there's a better way to do this... but that suffices.

Answer (score 0):

Grab them as an array, test the array length, and if more than zero, include them, otherwise show the message, as in this example:

```
<?php
$files = glob("overzicht/projects/*.php");
if (count($files) == 0)
{
    echo "There are no files found in the directory";
}
else
{
    foreach($files as $file)
    {
        include $file;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: result of `glob` is an array

Comment: @Peter I haven't used glob before so I wasn't aware of that. Have amended my code accordingly

Answer (score 0):

$`files = glob("overzicht/projects/*.php");
foreach (`$`files as $filename) {
    if(file_exist(`$`filename)) {
        include_once `$`filename;
    } else {
        echo 'there are no files found in the directory.\n';
    }
}
?>
If You have many files in you'r directory. Try this ... I hope it will come up

Answer (score -1):

Add a flag to detect if a file was found.

```
<?php   
$found = false;
foreach (glob("overzicht/projects/*.php") as $filename)
{
    if(file_exists($filename)) {
        include $filename;
        $found = true;
    }
}

if(!$found) {
    print("There are no files found in the directory.")
}
?>
```

Comment: Interesting usage of `if(file_exists($filename)) {`. Can you give us an example scenario where `glob` found some file but it doesn't exists?

Comment: @Peter Classic example of a brain fart.  I am used to using it for detecting files before inclusion.  For some reason I was thinking that by simply setting `$found = true` in the loop may have erroneously set the flag without the file check.  My mistake...